# PostgreSQL Error more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with a data query where I query a single column like this:

```
SELECT a.ad_morg_key, count(a.sid_mpenduduk_key) AS total_population 
FROM sid_mpenduduk a 
GROUP BY a.ad_morg_key;
```

[image: 1]

and it really works. But when I query with multiple columns with a query like this:

```
SELECT a.ad_morg_key, b."name", 
count(b.sid_magama_key) AS total, 
count(b.sid_magama_key)::float / (SELECT count(a.sid_mpenduduk_key) 
FROM sid_mpenduduk a 
GROUP BY a.ad_morg_key)::float * 100::float AS percentage,
(SELECT count(a.sid_mpenduduk_key) FROM sid_mpenduduk a GROUP BY a.ad_morg_key) AS total_population
FROM sid_mpenduduk a
INNER JOIN sid_magama b ON a.sid_magama_key = b.sid_magama_key
GROUP BY a.ad_morg_key, b."name";
```

But it fails with:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I want the final result like this :

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlation clause instead:

```
(SELECT count(a.sid_mpenduduk_key) 
 FROM sid_mpenduduk a2 
 WHERE a2.ad_morg_key = a.ad_morg_key
) AS total_population
```

I'm not sure if the subquery is really necessary.  So, you might consider asking a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: maybe u have another way to calculate population grouping based on ad_morg_key? I just want to calculate population group based on ad_morg_key

Comment: @Mr.Robot . . . As the answer suggests:  ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results and explanation.  These question has been answer, more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery is grouped by `a.ad_morg_key` so it will get you a row for each different value of `a.ad_morg_key`.

In general terms each subquery in a SELECT statement should return a single value. Suppose you have the following table called `A`.

| A_key | A_value |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 200 |
| A2 | 200 |

If you execute

```
SELECT (SELECT A_KEY FROM A) as keys
FROM A
```

the subquery `(SELECT A_KEY FROM A)` returns

| A_key |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A2 |

so what should be the value for `keys`?
SQL cannot handle this decision so you should pick one of the values or aggregate them into a single value.

Comment: right Horario so the `SELECT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(A_KEY) FROM A) as keys
FROM A` will do the work, or instead of  `ARRAY_AGG ` you could place another aggregate function (like count(...)) So with that you will have everything OK! You may add this the answer and it would be a hell of an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting burned by

```
GROUP BY ...
(SELECT count(a.sid_mpenduduk_key) 
 FROM sid_mpenduduk a 
 GROUP BY a.ad_morg_key) AS total_population
```

because the outer `GROUP BY` wants a scalar, but the subquery is producing a count for each `a.ad_morg_key`.

I don't write my queries that way.  Instead, produce a virtual table,

```
SELECT a.ad_morg_key, b."name", 
...
JOIN 
(SELECT ad_morg_key, 
        count(sid_mpenduduk_key) as N
 FROM sid_mpenduduk
 GROUP BY ad_morg_key) AS morgs
on ad_morg_key = morgs.ad_morg_key
```

That way, you have the count for each row as `N`, and you can divide at will,

```
count(b.sid_magama_key)::float / morgs.N
```

and, if you get tripped up, you'll have many more rows than you expected instead of an error message.